# Using Properties as Text Variables in Twincat 3

Tags: oop, plc, twincat, twincat-hmi, beckhof

I am trying to make a project, where I control variables read and write from the HMI/visualization through properties of function blocks. I am new to Twincat and OOP,and I am lost as to why I can pass a property as text variable to an element in visualization.
The error I am getting is:

[image]
[image]

I am doing it this way so that I can monitor when a change happens to the variables, such as a worker changing a value or smth.
Any idea on how this can fixed? Is this the case for HMI as well, or is it limited to visualizations?
THank you in advance.

Comment: HMI supports method and property binding. Try this, if it works `Main.fbSensor::P_AlaActive`

Comment: Never mind, this does not work. I would assume property binding to visualization is not supported - best to ask Beckhoff directly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Twincat PLC HMI or a .Net project. The twincat-hmi tag is for Twincat HMI HTML based visulisation TF2200.